# Autosys Equivalent of Style Cop?

Tags: stylecop, autosys

My company has an internal application that enforces their AutoSys naming convention, box failure / success paths, page job existance, etc.

I'm not an AutoSys user, but I've been tasked with rewriting this application to integrate it to our build process (it's currently in Visual FoxPro with no command line execution options).

Before I go off writing my C# app, I thought I'd research whether there is an off the shelf product designed to do this.  Something like Style Cop for AutoSys.

Some Google searches came up with nothing.  I'm not surprised, but wanted to see if anyone has experience with a product like this.  I find it plausible that it exists, and that I just didn't find it with my search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any. Just like you, I wrote my own in Perl. Mine enforces such standards as: Job names, owners and machines. Log file and profile paths and some but not all syntax errors. I would be interested to see what you came up with.

Comment: I wrote a Regex in my C# app that parsed on keyword and allowed me to quickly grab the values I needed.  I programatically enforce any rules necessary of a data structure that mimics the file (JobSet object with a list of Job classes) that I parse the file into.  Thanks for your answer / combination.  I'd love to post the Regex, but I've moved off that project and didn't keep a copy of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Based on not finding anything, and no results here, I'm going ahead and writing it myself.